# JOGL does not work after reinstalling ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl, ubuntu-10.10

i had a fully work project in ubuntu 9 with eclipse. Now i have installed Ubuntu 10.10, get the backup back, downloaded Eclipse and try to run the project.

The project folder was not changed at all!
But now it does not work:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path

If i go to "project properties > java build path > libraries" gluegen-rt.jar and jogl.jar are present and i have no compilation error ("*import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;*" has no error so classes are loaded correctly i think)

i tried to install JOGL from synaptic too.

Here the full error stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   gluegen-rt in java.library.path   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
>     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
>     at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
>     at
>   com.sun.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:51)
>     at
>   com.sun.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader$1.run(NativeLibLoader.java:70)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.sun.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadGlueGenRT(NativeLibLoader.java:68)
>     at
>   com.sun.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibrary.ensureNativeLibLoaded(NativeLibrary.java:399)
>     at
>   com.sun.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibrary.open(NativeLibrary.java:163)
>     at
>   com.sun.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibrary.open(NativeLibrary.java:129)
>     at
>   com.sun.opengl.impl.x11.DRIHack.begin(DRIHack.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.opengl.impl.x11.X11GLDrawableFactory.(X11GLDrawableFactory.java:99)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
>     at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.getFactory(GLDrawableFactory.java:111)
>     at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLJPanel.initialize(GLJPanel.java:889)
>     at
>   javax.media.opengl.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:488)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:866)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:866)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:866)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:866)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:866)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:581)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:866)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5145)
>     at
>   javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:302)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1145)
>     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
>     at
>   java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
>     at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
>     at
>   java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1844)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:751)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:696)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:676)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:57)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1550)
>     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:647)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:617)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem!

**ECLIPSE SAVE ABSOLUTE PATH OF EXTERNAL JARS**

In your eclipse project properties -> Java Build Path, go to your library, find the gluegen-rt.jar, expand it, and click on Native Library Location and enter the location for the native libraries that came with your JOGL download.

after reinstallin ubuntu i changed my home folder structures.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to edit the Native Library Location when using JOGL 2 as long as you put the JARs containing the native libraries into the same directory than the JARs containing the Java libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me figure out how to get Eclipse to use the Processing Libraries ( of http://processing.org ) with OpenGL.  I know processing has its own editor, but it isn't very feature rich.

So I had this error:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
```

so I had to *Right Click* on the `jogl.all.jar` jar file in the "Project Explorer", *Click* "Properties", *Click* "Native Library" and set the "Location Path".

My Location Path was:

`/home/username/Desktop/processing-2.0a4/modes/java/libraries/opengl/library/linux32`

After that it worked perfect!

Comment: jogl.all.jar has been renamed jogl-all.jar in JOGL 2